# Entity Framework foreign key is null

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, foreign-keys, asp.net-core-7.0

When trying to create an `Edificio` that contains a relationship with another table (`Facultad`) in the database, it does not allow it to be stored and the `EdiFac` virtual public foreign key in model `Edificio`  appears null. The `modelState` will not allow saving until everything is true and valid. Help me please to find a solution.

Model class `Facultad`:

```
namespace web_uni_mvc.Models;

public partial class Facultad
{
    public int FacId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nombre de la Facultad")]
    public string FacNombre { get; set; } = null!;

    [Display(Name = "Estatus de la Facultad")]
    public string FacEstatus { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<Edificio> Edificios { get; set; } = new List<Edificio>();
}
```

Model class `Edificio`:

```
namespace web_uni_mvc.Models;

public partial class Edificio
{
    [Key]
    public int EdiId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nombre del Edificio")]
    public string EdiNombre { get; set; } = null!;

    [Display(Name = "Numero de Aulas")]
    public int EdiNumAulas { get; set; }

    //[Display(Name = "Facultad")]
    [Required]
    public int EdiFacId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Estatus")]
    public string EdiEstatus { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<Aula> Aulas { get; set; } = new List<Aula>();

    [Required]
    public virtual Facultad EdiFac { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

`UniversidadContext`:

```
namespace web_uni_mvc.Models;

public partial class UniversidadContext : DbContext
{
    public UniversidadContext()
    {
    }

    public UniversidadContext(DbContextOptions<UniversidadContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Aula> Aulas { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Edificio> Edificios { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Facultad> Facultads { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Aula>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.AulId).HasName("PK__Aula__A8EA7F0A995FB5E8");

            entity.ToTable("Aula");

            entity.Property(e => e.AulId).HasColumnName("Aul_Id");
            entity.Property(e => e.AulEdiId).HasColumnName("Aul_Edi_Id");
            entity.Property(e => e.AulEstatus)
                .HasMaxLength(1)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("Aul_Estatus");
            entity.Property(e => e.AulNumero).HasColumnName("Aul_Numero");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.AulEdi).WithMany(p => p.Aulas)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.AulEdiId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__Aula__Aul_Edi_Id__3C69FB99");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Edificio>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.EdiId).HasName("PK__Edificio__F567AB14B5C3D23D");

            entity.ToTable("Edificio");

            entity.Property(e => e.EdiId).HasColumnName("Edi_Id");
            entity.Property(e => e.EdiEstatus)
                .HasMaxLength(1)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("Edi_Estatus");
            entity.Property(e => e.EdiFacId).HasColumnName("Edi_Fac_Id");
            entity.Property(e => e.EdiNombre)
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("Edi_Nombre");
            entity.Property(e => e.EdiNumAulas).HasColumnName("Edi_Num_Aulas");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.EdiFac).WithMany(p => p.Edificios)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.EdiFacId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__Edificio__Edi_Fa__398D8EEE");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Facultad>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.FacId).HasName("PK__Facultad__58357016F79198D0");

            entity.ToTable("Facultad");

            entity.Property(e => e.FacId).HasColumnName("Fac_Id");
            entity.Property(e => e.FacEstatus)
                .HasMaxLength(1)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("Fac_Estatus");
            entity.Property(e => e.FacNombre)
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("Fac_Nombre");
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

`Edificio` controller:

```
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["EdiFacId"] = new SelectList(_context.Facultads, "FacId", "FacNombre");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Edificios/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("EdiId,EdiNombre,EdiNumAulas,EdiFacId,EdiEstatus")] Edificio edificio)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(edificio);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        ViewData["EdiFacId"] = new SelectList(_context.Facultads, "FacId", "FacNombre", edificio.EdiFacId);
        return View(edificio);
        
    }
```

Create view for `Edificio`:

```
        <div class="form-group pb-3">
            <label asp-for="EdiFacId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="EdiFacId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.EdiFacId"></select>
        </div>
```

I want to create `Edificio` instances. It's using .NET 7.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: Do not pass entities between views and controllers.

Yes, many "official" examples out there do just that. No, it is a very bad practice which leads to many problems as soon as you get into examples more complicated than saving a ToDo "entity" as well as exposing you to a solution that opens the door to data tampering.

The core reason things like this don't work is that when you pass an entity from controller to serve as the Model for a view, you are passing the entity to the View Engine. This takes the cshtml and composes HTML and a nugget of JS to pass to the client browser. When the client browser captures a form submit or you make an Ajax / POST back to the server exposing a method that accepts an Entity as the parameter, the MVC JS or your own JS needs to build a new instance of an entity to send it. Where is it getting this entity from on the HTML and JS side of the web? It scrapes the fields from the various controls in the HTML.

Think of it this way, if you were to write a JavaScript method in your page to call a server action that accepts an entity, especially an entity that had related entities, how would you need to do it? For a start you would need to create a new instance. `@Model` doesn't exist to the Client HTML/JS. This is why you need to do things like add `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ToDoId)` for fields in an entity that you don't display with text boxes etc. This is so that when the JS scrapes together the form data to send with a POST, it can fill in a value for ToDoId. Technically if you wanted to reconstruct an entire valid object graph of an entity and its related entities, every property of every related entity would need to reside somewhere in the HTML and/or JS.  Is that possible? Yes. Is it recommended? Absolutely not. (Basically reinventing ViewState from the good 'ol ASP days.)

So in a nutshell, what you send to the view as a Model is not persisted client-side to be magically sent back to the server. Even if you do persist a representation client side (which is possible) this should never be done for Entity graphs or you can expect to fall foul of lazy loading and you are exposing everything about your domain for client-side inspection. Even then, when it is sent back to the server it is nothing more than a deserialized copy of the data, not the same instance that was initially sent. It should never be trusted, and you're still going to face problems trying to deal with tracked references.

Instead of sending entities to the view, compose a view model with just the data the view needs, and accept a view model or individual values representing just the data you need coming back. Server-side you can load and update entities as needed. This can help break bad habits around what data is actually being passed around, can be safer for serializing and storing client-side, and will generally be better performing than trying to pass entities around. Entities represent data state and should only be concerned with data state, not view state.